# Counting number of rows in the table of mysql database and printing in django webapplication

Tags: html, django

I have successfully connected Django forms with backend (MySQL) , now I have to count the rows in the table created and print its output in an HTML webpage of my Django web application.

How can I do it?

[image: Picture for Clarification]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

on your `views.py`

```py
def count_rows(request):
    # if you created table with model and migrations
    return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'count': ModelName.objects.count()})

    # if you created table manually
    from django.db import connection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1")
        count = len(cursor.fetchall)
    return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'count': count})
```

on your `urls.py`

````
# import all from your ```views.py``` file
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('count-rows/',count_rows,name='countrows' ),
    # ...
]
````

on your template just type this

```
{{ count }}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you meant by userModelName and your-template.html

Comment: the `ModelName` * is your table name if you make your table via model and migrations. the `your-template.html` is the page where you want to print count.

Comment: But I have not created the table using models instead I have used views.py and created a function to import values to a already created table and database

Comment: can you explain what you meant by import all from your views.py file?

Comment: `from views.py import *`

Comment: @RajeelRajput: please don't use a wildcard import: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/from_module_import_all_used.html this is an antipattern.